unusual error while linking Howard Hinnat's date time library
I am trying to link following code
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    //using namespace std;
    //using namespace chrono;

    auto tz = locate_zone("America/New_York");
    return 0;
}

I am using following compilation lines
g++ -fsigned-char -g -O0 -std=c++17 -I/home/user1/date-master_debug/include -I/home/user1/date-master_debug -m64 -Wfatal-errors -c hh_is_dst.cc -o hh_is_dst.o

g++ -g -O0 -std=c++17 -I/home/user1/date-master_debug/include -m64 -Wfatal-errors -o hh_is_dst hh_is_dst.o -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -Wl,-Bstatic -L/home/user1/date-master_debug/build -ldate-tz -Wl,-Bdynamic -lstdc++ -lgcc -lgcc_eh -Wl,-Bdynamic -lm -lcrypt -lc -lrt -lpthread

Getting following error
hh_is_dst.o: In function `main': /home/user1/hh_is_dst.cc:12: undefined reference to date::locate_zone(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Any idead why it is asking for above definition ? Or Am I missing something?
I have just compiled date time library with following commands
CXX=g++ CC=gcc CXXFLAGS='-g -O0 -fexceptions -std=c++17' /home/user1/utilities/cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake --debug-trycompile --debug-output -DENABLE_DATE_TESTING=ON -DBUILD_TZ_LIB=ON -DMANUAL_TZ_DB=ON -DUSE_TZ_DB_IN_DOT=ON ../

CXX=g++ CC=gcc CXXFLAGS='-g -O0 -fexceptions -std=c++17' /home/user1/utilities/cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake --build . --target testit --verbose

Library got created with one test case failed.
using following environment

cat /etc/redhat-release


Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.10 (Ootpa)
gcc --version


gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22)
g++ --version


g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22)

Actually I got error when I tried to add code in my application. This is minimal example that I can reproduce.

OT: Who told you to use the flags, options and libraries you use when building? You don't need all of that, especially the libraries.

You are trying to link to a library named libdate-tz, but either the linker cannot find it, or it does not containn the method date::locate_zone. Incidentally, it is much better to use fully qualified names in C++ rather than relying on using statements.

I suspect that the date-tz lib does not match the header files. I got a similar issue when rebasing my date clone without rebuilding libdate-tz.

https://godbolt.org/z/69djnvahq

For whatever reason you are not linking to tz.cpp (where date::locate_zone is defined).  Imho, the easiest thing to do is not not use the CMake build system and just compile and link to tz.cpp.
I recommend following the build instructions here:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation
Whatever configuration flags you use, you'll need to use the same ones for both your files (that include tz.h) and tz.cpp.
Note that if you can use gcc-14 and C++20, this library is obsoleted by <chrono>.  E.g. use std::chrono::locate_zone instead.

We just want to keep this code separate from our main application code. I am using std=c++17 flag with above compiler version. So does above statement still holds true ?

Prior to gcc-14 and C++20, you need this library for this functionality.

After compiling tz.cpp separately with my application compile  options issue got resolved
